# Angular: Editable table as a existing component

Tags: angular

I am looking for a existing component that allows me to have a table of records with edit/delete/new of rows.

Does such an adaptable component exist in any library?

Comment: There are a lot package available for this  1. https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/tables/editable/ 2. https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/ 3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-editable-table

Answer (score 1):

You can look into 
[PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/)

it consists of many components which you can use in your angular project
Heres the link for [Table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table)